# How to set value in file through terminal?

Tags: shell

I want to set a variable from "yes" to "no" through my shell script how do I do it? here is my command that I'm executing...

```
cat sshd_config | grep "PasswordAuthentication"
```

And this is the output that I get...

```
#PasswordAuthentication yes
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
```

Here the first line that is `#PasswordAuthentication yes` is the one that I want to change it to `#PasswordAuthentication no` without any editor directly through my shell script. Please help me with the same. Thank you.

Comment: Surely the `#` at the start of the line means you are only changing a comment? Which will have no effect on anything.

Answer (score 2):

May be this

```
perl -pi -e 's/PasswordAuthentication yes/PasswordAuthentication no/g' sshd_config
```

alternatively you could use `sed`

```
sed -i 's/PasswordAuthentication yes/PasswordAuthentication no/g' sshd_config
```